# Failed to compile libusbx during Android make

Tags: android, gcc, automake, libusb-1.0

I am trying to compile CM 12.1 for my device. While building, I get below error. I have libusb-1.0-0-dev installed also. What am I missing?

If I compile only 1 file with cflags,I am able to get the .o file but while building whole code, how do I specify Make file to work.

With gcc:(Success)

```
gcc external/libusbx/examples/listdevs.c -o out/target/product/bacon/obj/EXECUTABLES/listdevs_intermediates/listdevs.o `pkg-config --libs --cflags libusb-1.0`
```

With Android make :(Failure)

```
   external/libusbx/android/jni/../../examples/listdevs.c:22:20: fatal error: libusb.h: No such file or directory

 #include "libusb.h"

compilation terminated.
build/core/binary.mk:699: recipe for target '/home/risingup/CM12.1/out/target/product/bacon/obj/EXECUTABLES/listdevs_intermediates/../../examples/listdevs.o' failed
make: *** [/home/risingup/CM12.1/out/target/product/bacon/obj/EXECUTABLES/listdevs_intermediates/../../examples/listdevs.o] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file '/home/risingup/CM12.1/out/target/product/bacon/obj/EXECUTABLES/listdevs_intermediates/../../examples/listdevs.o'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue by adding this to .repo/local_manifests/local_manifests.xml and repo syncing. I thought these weren't necessary as I extracted propetierary blobs from my phone using ./extract-files.sh but that wasnt' the case. My bad.. And also,make clobber and build again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
<project name="TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_oppo" path="vendor/oppo" remote="github" revision="cm-12.1" />
<project name="TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_oneplus" path="vendor/oneplus" remote="github" revision="cm-12.1" />
</manifest>
```

P.S. Also for future readers, make sure you create a swap file of 4 gb or more because build process takes lot of memory especially for building libwebviewchromium.so.